# Do you need to synchronize a buffer if only one thread adds and only one (different) thread removes?

Tags: java, synchronization, buffer

I hava a java application that uses Buffers to pass object around between threads.  Generally I synchronize these buffers using BufferUtils.  If I have just one thread that adds objects to a buffer, and only adds, and just one other thread that removes objects from the buffer, and only removes; does the buffer between them need to be synchronized?

I have a situation now where the two threads in question are instantiated from spring beans and can only get their hands on the shared buffer by having a third bean for the buffer that they both reference.  I couldn't figure out how to make a synchronized buffer from a bean, hence the question regarding whether or not it was necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could use a BlockingQueue to pass those objects around. And the blocking queue is thread safe. Plus it offers several put/get variants that can be used nicely. 
The method put, for instance, will make the thread block until there is enough room in the queue.
Offer method, can be used with a timeout, so if it doesn't manage to add to the queue it will return false.

You could check it out
[BlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html)

Comment: Thank you, this did exactly what I needed.  Plus, it does have some very nice methods for timeouts adding objects, boolean return on add instead of catching a BufferOverflow.  Very nice indeed, Thanks!

Comment: This is almost a second question, but hardly worth making a whole new post over.  Do you know how BlockingQueue compares to a buffer synchronized with BufferUtils as far as performance goes?

Comment: Sorry for the (very) late reply.. Well you should really run some tests in order to know for sure. My belief is that BlockingQueue variants are well written and efficient. They are part of the concurrent package that was added in Java 5, if I'm not mistaken. But in the end, you should do some tests and do some measurements, to see if the way you used is suiting you. You might want to look at  the available classes and choose from Array back or LinkedList backed queues. See the above docs for details.  Cheers, Tiberiu

Answer (score 1):

Yes the buffer will need to be synchronized. Per the Java memory model if more than one thread are accessing the same datastructure without synchronization there is no guarantee that changes made by one thread are visible to the other threads. Some form of the BlockingQueue should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I would use an Exchanger.  This allows two threads to swap to buffers (the producer a full buffer and the consumer an emptied buffer)

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Exchanger.html

My article on the Exchanger for swapping ByteBuffers.

http://vanillajava.blogspot.com/2011/09/exchange-and-gc-less-java.html